# Automatically deploying assets to Rackspace CDN via git and updating references to those assets?

Tags: git, deployment, cdn, rackspace-cloud

I'm looking for some help in designing a strategy to automate deployment of a web application's assets (images, css, js) to Rackspace's Cloud Files (CDN) service.

I currently use git push to deploy the web app to a remote server. So here's one way I'm thinking this could happen. Are there any better/cleaner methods?

- Dev makes changes to an asset file (css, js, or an image)
- Dev commits his changes
- Dev pushes his changes to the server
- Assets are automatically renamed to eliminate cache issues (append git version?) and sent to the CDN
- Referencing code would be automatically updated to new filename

FYI, this is a PHP app in CodeIgniter 2.x if it matters.

Happy to hear any ideas, alternative or not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379380

Comment: I recently faced the same problem and found the ``swift`` console tool to be very useful for scripted upload to rackspace cloud files. see my answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/421622/sync-mirror-directory-with-rackspace-cloud-files-bucket/659209#659209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found anything to automatically do it.

You can use the Rack Space Cloud File API ( http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/api/ ) to upload files to Rackspace's CDN aware containers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything, but you could probably script something to do this without too much work.

Check out [Fog](https://github.com/geemus/fog) or the official [ruby-cloudfiles](https://github.com/rackspace/ruby-cloudfiles) gem from Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/phillc/cloud-files-asset-sync

Answer (score 0):

This github repository will do at least part of what you are asking.

https://github.com/bermi/cloudfiles-mirror

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP you should seriously consider using the [Rackspace PHP SDK](http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/guide/content/php.html). You can find [sample code for working with the CDN service](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/samples/objectstore/cdn.php). It'll be a lot easier to work with than writing directly to the Cloud Files API.

Answer (score 0):

There's a paid service http://beanstalkapp.com/features/deployments for auto deployments to cloud files or other servers.

Answer (score 0):

try this its completely automated:  https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync